# Conversion teradata to mysql aurora without analytical function

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.6, teradata-sql-assistant, amazon-aurora

> I have mysql aurora 5.6 version so can't use analytical function. I am
> not getting any fruitful comment from anywhere. Please help to fix the
> query

***Teradata query:***

```
select * from xyz qualify row_number() over (partition by source_job_id, run_date, source_job_id, source_parent_job_id order by source_job_id, run_date, source_job_id, source_parent_job_id)=1
```

***MYSQL Query ( Partially wrong as I don't know how to use multiple partition column)***

```
SELECT T.*, RowNum
FROM(
  SELECT T.*, 
    IF(@last_source_job_id = source_job_id, @I:=@I+1, @I:=1) RowNum,
    @last_source_job_id := source_job_id
  FROM  xyz T,(SELECT @last_source_job_id:=NULL, @I:=0)I
  ORDER BY  source_job_id, run_date, source_job_id, source_parent_job_id
)T where RowNum=1;
```

**

> Updated Query

**

```
SELECT T.*, RowNum
FROM(
  SELECT T.*, 
    IF(@last_source_job_id = source_job_id and @last_run_date=run_date and @last_source_parent_job_id=source_parent_job_id, @I:=@I+1, @I:=1) RowNum,
    @last_source_job_id := source_job_id and @last_run_date:=run_date and @last_source_parent_job_id:=source_parent_job_id
    
  FROM  xyz T
  ORDER BY  source_job_id, run_date, source_job_id, source_parent_job_id
)T where RowNum=1;
```

Comment: It is not going to be pretty since you have 4 columns in your partition.  You need 1 variable for each one, and your IF would be: `IF(@last_source_job_id = source_job_id AND @last_run_date = run_date AND ..., ` It is a bit odd that the ORDER BY contains exactly the same columns as PARTITION BY. It means that each partition is ordered randomly

Comment: @lennart Are you suggesting which I have updated in my description.

Comment: I don't think (but I might be wrong) that you can do assignments like: `@last_source_job_id := source_job_id and @last_run_date:=run_date ...`